# How to insert natural lighting with different illuminance values through window inside a room in blender?

Tags: rendering, lighting

I have created a very simple model of a room with windows. I have calculated illuminance values for different walls, ceiling and floor of the room through mathematical formula. I want to display lighting in the room depending on the illuminance values. For example, the illuminance at the far end of room (opposite to window) is very much lower than the illuminance near the window.
I cannot find anything in blender where I can input different illuminance values and show the result accordingly. Is there anyway to achieve this ?
Here is a snapshot of my room

[image: Room with windows in blender]

Comment: What is the goal of this work, why do you calculate it by yourself, instead letting blender do this job for you?

Comment: Actually, I want to use RGB values from a csv file and use it to show how different does walls of the room look like. The values are calculated very precisely for another purpose of a study and I just want to show a real time depiction of how the room is supposed to look.

Comment: Why don't you draw wall texture based on csv and when apply this texture as shadlles  material?